# Netbeans uses all shared memory

Tags: ram, netbeans

Recently I noticed that when Netbeans is running, many other programs look strange when I run them,for example VLC's "floating controls" look transparent, and there is an overlap of text in the non floating controls (making the current position in the film unreadable) It is also impossible to change position within the film.

Other applications that have problems are TexMaker and Skype.

If I exit Netbeans and restart the programs they work fine.

I think this is a problem with shared memory. I have 32GB ram - so memory should not be a problem, nor was it in the past. However, even if Netbeans is running for only a few minutes my shared memory usage increases drastically. `ipcs` shows approximately 40 entries with no Netbeans and 400 with Netbeans (literally just starting it).

Is this a bug in Netbeans, or Ubuntu, or neither? How can I either increase my shared memory so that other applications run fine with Netbeans on, or how do I reduce Netbeans shared memory

Edit:

After 5 minutes without using it, just leaving it idle, the shared memory entries increased to 850.